# Integrate curve given in polar coords solution verification

Tags: definite-integrals, solution-verification, polar-coordinates

My solution to the below problem is $4\pi$ but the answer sheet says it's $8\pi$. Please verify my calculations:

$$
\rho=4\sin2\phi \implies 4\sin2\phi \ge0 \implies \sin t\ge 0
$$

Where $t = 2\phi$

Now, I'm trying to find the integration bounds like this:

$$
t \in [0 + 2k\pi, \pi+2k\pi], k\in Z \\
0+2k\pi \le t \le\pi+2k\pi \\
0+2k\pi \le 2\phi \le\pi+2k\pi \\
k\pi \le \phi \le \frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi \\
0 \le \phi \le \frac{\pi}{2} \vee \pi \le \phi \le \frac{3\pi}{2}\\
$$

Therefore the integrals should be:

$$
\frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} 16\sin^22\phi\  d\phi + \frac{1}{2} \int_{\pi}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} 16\sin^22\phi\  d\phi = \\
8 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^22\phi\ d\phi + 8 \int_{\pi}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} \sin^22\phi\  d\phi
$$

The indefinite integral is:

$$
\int \sin^22\phi\ d\phi = \frac{1}{2}\phi - \frac{1}{8}\sin4\phi + C
$$

And so I continue the calculations:

$$
8\left[\frac{1}{2}\phi-\frac{1}{8}\sin4\phi\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} + 8\left[\frac{1}{2}\phi-\frac{1}{8}\sin4\phi\right]_{\pi}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} = 4\pi
$$

This got to be something simple...

**EDIT**

The problem I'm trying to solve is to calculate the area of a figure bounded by a curve given by the first equation in this question.

Comment: Can you post the complete question? Not sure what you are trying to do. It is hard to verify unless we know what is the question. Where do you get $16\sin^2 2\phi $ for  the integral from?

Comment: @MathLover I've edited the question.

Comment: Do you know this is rose curve with $4$ petals?

Comment: Now I know :) But what about my solution? :D

Comment: You have done it correctly but you have only considered $2$ petals. There are $4$ petals. Please see the bounds in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the bound -

i) For $0 \le \phi \le \frac{\pi}{2}, 0 \le 2\phi \le \pi$.

ii) For $\frac{\pi}{2} \le \phi \le \pi, \pi \le 2\phi \le 2\pi$.

iii) For $\pi \le \phi \le \frac{3\pi}{2}, 2\pi \le 2\phi \le 3\pi$.

iv) For $\frac{3\pi}{2} \le \phi \le 2\pi, 3\pi \le 2\phi \le 4\pi$.

This is rose curve with $4$ petals.

(i) gives you the petal in first quadrant, (ii) gives you the petal in the fourth quadrant and so on...

Given we have to find area bound by this curve, let's find area of one of the petals and multiply by $4$.

Area of the petal in the first quadrant $= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} 16\sin^22\phi\  d\phi $

$= 8 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^22\phi\  d\phi = 8\left[\frac{1}{2}\phi-\frac{1}{8}\sin4\phi\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} = 2\pi$

Total area $= 4 \times 2\pi = 8\pi$

Or you can apply the bound (ii), (iii), (iv) in the integral to get to total area $8\pi$.

Comment: Shouldn’t the bounds be constrained to sin function base period, which is $2\pi$ ?

Comment: yes that is correct. that is why I took $0$ to $\pi/2$ for the first petal. Please see bounds of $\phi$ in (i), (ii), (iii), (iv).

Comment: I have shown bounds of $2\phi$ so you know the graph of each petal.

Comment: the bound will be constrained by angle $\phi$ between 0 and $2\pi$, not $2\phi$.

Comment: Tbh, I'm still a bit confused, maybe because I misunderstood the way of finding the bounds that my course presented. However I think your answer puts me on the right track, so thanks.

Comment: After googling a bit I found out what you kind of said - that to find the integration bounds I should draw the curve. Fair enough, but what about more complex graphs? Isn't there an analytical (non-graphical) way of finding those bounds?

Comment: For rose curves, $n$ in $a \sin n \theta$ decided the number of petals.  Once you read through, it will be easier to understand the bounds and integrate.

Comment: You said there are 4 petals, but n here is 2. Now I'm even more confused :D. Also: what should I read?

Comment: I said $n$ decides number of petals, not that number of petals = n. For even values of $n$, number of petals = $2n$. For odd values of $n$, they overlap and it is more complicated. Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_(mathematics)